# The function acquiring client IP address causes a memory leak

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, webrtc

I am creating an application acquiring the client's IP address frequently (about per second) in JavaScript.
Because of a possible BAN, I do not want to use services providing the client's IP address such as [l2.io](https://l2.io/) if I can.
Also, I do not want to prepare the API providing the client's IP address on my web server if I can.

I found WebRTC helpful to solve the problem and tried writing the function acquiring the client's IP address using WebRTC.
It seems that the function works well but I found the function causing a memory leak.

The following is my code causing a memory leak in Chrome 47.

```js
function getIpAddress() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var RTCPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection
            || window.mozRTCPeerConnection
            || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
        var pc = new RTCPeerConnection({
            iceServers: [{urls: "stun:stun.services.mozilla.com"}]
        }, {
            optional: [{RtpDataChannels: true}]
        });
        pc.onicecandidate = ice => {
            if (pc.iceGatheringState == "complete" && ice.candidate === null) { // waiting for completion
                resolve(pc.localDescription.sdp.split("\r\n").filter(line => line.indexOf("c=") == 0)[0].split(" ")[2]);
                if (pc.signalingState != "closed") pc.close();
            }
        };
        pc.createDataChannel("");
        pc.createOffer(result => {
            pc.setLocalDescription(result, function () {}, function () {});
        }, function () {});
    });
}

// calling getIpAddress many times causes a memory leak
(function loop() {
    getIpAddress().then(loop);
})();
```

Do you know which part of `getIpAddress` causes a memory leak?
If you do not know, is there another way to acquire the client's IP address without a memory leak?

#### Note:

I have already tried [webrtc-ips](https://github.com/diafygi/webrtc-ips) but it seems that webrtc-ips also causes a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that looping the WebRTC request is planned "by design". 
Do you have a memory leak when doing the function only once ?
Normally, you need to catch the IP only once by client.

In my firefox, no memory leak, only a big processor charge because of the loop.

If you can use PHP, acquiring IP address would be very easy.

Comment: I need the _latest_ IP address.
If there are ways to catch the change of IP address, it is better than monitoring.
In my Firefox 43 on Windows 7 (64bit), a memory leak occured.

Answer (score 0):

> Do you know which part of `getIpAddress` causes a memory leak?

It seems that instantiating `RTCPeerConnection` many times causes a memory leak.
The following code causes a memory leak and may crash Chrome 47 and Firefox 43.

```js
while (true) {
    var RTCPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection
        || window.mozRTCPeerConnection
        || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
    var pc = new RTCPeerConnection({});
    pc.close();
}
```